# Python Matplotlib: Issue on updating matplotlib to 3.1.2 on windows

Tags: python, matplotlib, anaconda, conda

Following the release of Matplotlib to the 3.1.2 version I am having issues updating my package version.

I tried:

- `conda install -c conda-forge matplotlib=3.1.2` in Jupyter notebook (Without success, the code kept running for 20 mins before I interrupted); in the Anaconda prompt with the following failed result:

> (base) C:\Users\Adrien>conda install -c conda-forge matplotlib=3.1.2
>   Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done Solving
>   environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible
>   solve. Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done Solving
>   environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible
>   solve. Solving environment: | Found conflicts! Looking for
>   incompatible packages. This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to
>   abort. failed

- `conda update matplotlib` with the following result:

> (base) C:\Users\Adrien>conda update matplotlib Collecting package
>   metadata (current_repodata.json): done Solving environment: /
>
> Updating matplotlib is constricted by
>
> anaconda -> requires matplotlib==3.1.1=py37hc8f65d3_0
>
> If you are sure you want an update of your package either try `conda
>   update --all` or install a specific version of the package you want
>   using `conda install <pkg>=<version>`
>
> done
>
> ### Package Plan
>
> environment location: C:\Users\Adrien\Anaconda3
>
> added / updated specs:
>       - matplotlib
>
> The following packages will be downloaded:
>
> ```
> package                    |            build
> ---------------------------|-----------------
> backports.functools_lru_cache-1.6.1|             py_0          11 KB
> conda-4.8.3                |           py37_0         2.8 MB
> future-0.18.2              |           py37_0         656 KB
> ------------------------------------------------------------
>                                        Total:         3.5 MB
> ```
>
> The following packages will be UPDATED:
>
> backports.functoo~                               1.5-py_2 -->
>   1.6.1-py_0   conda                                        4.8.2-py37_0 --> 4.8.3-py37_0   future                                      0.17.1-py37_0 --> 0.18.2-py37_0
>
> Proceed ([y]/n)? y
>
> Downloading and Extracting Packages conda-4.8.3          | 2.8 MB    |
>
> ################################################################## | 100% future-0.18.2        | 656 KB    |
>   
>   ################################################################## | 100% backports.functools_ | 11 KB     |
>   
>   ################################################################## | 100% Preparing transaction: done Verifying transaction: done
>
> Executing transaction: done
>
> (base) C:\Users\Adrien>import matplotlib 'import' is not recognized as
>   an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

And after restarting the system and Jupyter as you guess:

```
import matplotlib
print('matplotlib: {}'.format(matplotlib.__version__))
```

> matplotlib: 3.1.1

Any idea on what could be the next step ?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either you do:

```
conda update --all
```

or you try:

```
conda install matplotlib=3.1.2
```

Comment: Hi David, thank you for your suggestions, `conda install matplotlib=3.1.2` worked this time. matplotlib updated to 3.1.3 directly and corrected the bug I was experiencing on the previous version